# how to use one thread to listening all subscribe channel for redis？

Tags: python, multithreading, redis, publish-subscribe, coroutine

I use python 3.6.3, the channel build dynamically. 
the redis_client build when the client connect to webwsocket server.

I have about 1000 to 100,0000 redis_clients, every redis_client subscribe some channels.

How to use one thread or IOLoop listenning all clients message?
Can you give me an example which the thread can add new pubsub object to listening more channels?

Is there any solution use coroutine replace thread waiting here and can join all coroutine together (can not use joinall as some listener will approach later on.)
I using redis-py library.

Comment: I think you can get it by using ```https://redis.io/commands/client-list```.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, what you're looking for is Redis' [`PSUBSCRIBE`](https://redis.io/commands/psubscribe) command. Here's an example that shows how you can use it with redis-py and a listener thread:

```
import threading
import redis

class Listener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, r, p):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.redis = r
        self.pubsub = self.redis.pubsub()
        self.pubsub.psubscribe(p)

    def run(self):
        for m in self.pubsub.listen():
            if 'pmessage' != m['type']:
                continue
            if '__admin__' == m['channel'] and 'shutdown' == m['data']:
                print 'Listener shutting down, bye bye.'
                break
            print '[{}]: {}'.format(m['channel'], m['data'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = redis.StrictRedis()
    client = Listener(r, '*')
    client.start()

    r.publish('channel1', 'message1')
    r.publish('channel2', 'message2')
    r.publish('channel1', 'message3')

    r.publish('__admin__', 'shutdown')
    print 'Main ended.'
```

Comment: I can not use psubscribe, as there is many redis clients, when the client get message, they will transmit the message to different user, diffterent channel for different users.  The channel number is the same as user account. if I use psubscribe, I got all channels messages, how to I distinguish those message below to which user?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand your question.

Comment: OP has a valid question, client wants to subscribe to specific channels and not a specific pattern in a single thread. Both options subscribe to many channels underneath on Redis side that this client needs to be notified based on specific channels or specific channel pattern.

However, the client side requires a separate thread per channel subscription whereas a channel pattern subscription only requires one thread.